# Trying to return a class object from another class C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello I've been trying to return an object from a class but for some reason, whenever I try to return it, it fails but all other surrounding code works perfectly.

**emp.h**

```
class drvr{
private:
    string title;
    string empname;
public:
    drvr(string titlez, string name){
    title = titlez;
    empname = name;
    }
```

**node.h**

```
class node{
private:
    drvr edata(string, string);
    node * next;
public:
    node(emp rec){
       edata(rec);
       next = NULL;
    }
   drvr getData(){
   return edata;
   }
```

I get the error:

> cannot convert 'node::data' from type 'drve (node::)(int,
>   std::__cxx11::string) {aka drvr (node::)(int,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string)}' to type 'drvr'|

Comment: `edata` is a function that returns a `drvr`. It's not a `drvr`.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: use [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead of `NULL`.

Comment: It's seems to me, from the error message and because the provided code has other errors, that the provided code did not generate that error.

Comment: Also, the `drvr` class does not have a constructor that takes an `emp` object as a parameter. (And consider using more descriptive names: `driver`, `employee`, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `drvr edata(string, string);` you are actually declaring a function named `edata` that returns a `drvr` and takes two `string`.

To make it a variable initialized with `string` use `{}`.

```
drvr edata{"hello", "world"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  declaring  `edata` as a member function of class `node` that takes two arguments of type `std::string` and returns `drvr` object , but inside `getData` you are returning the address of that function , so the compiler tells you that the type of the object you are returning does not much what it expects this method to be returning as a type , obviously that's not what you want to do . i can see from the code that you are coding a `linked-list` , so `edata` should be of type `drvr` and it should be defined like this :
`drvr edata;`

And for setting a value for that attribute you can add a method to `node` :

```
void setEdata(const drvr & d )
{
this->edata = d;
}
```

or

```
void setEdata(const std::string & title,const std::string & empname )
    {
    this->edata = drvr(title,empname);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
class drvr {
private:
    string title;
    string empname;
public:
    drvr(string titlez, string name) {
        title = titlez;
        empname = name;
    }
    drvr(const drvr& other)
    {
        title = other.title;
        empname = other.empname;
    }

};    

class node {    
private:
    drvr edata;
    node * next;
public:
    node(const drvr& rec)
        :edata(rec)
    {
        next = nullptr;
    }

    drvr getData()
    {
        return edata;
    }
};
```